# django loaddata fails because of concurrent database query

Tags: django

I am trying to migrate the database of one my django projects from sqlite to mysql. I first dumped the whole thing with `./manage.py dumpdata > dump.json` and prepared the database with `./manage.py migrate` and deleted any created data in the tables (This was necessary, as the dump holds *all* the data).

When I wanted to import the data into the new database with `./manage.py loaddata`, there were a lot of errors I was able to resolve, but I can't find the source of this error:

```
Processed 330984 object(s).Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 109, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 175, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 205, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 904, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 954, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 664, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1199, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 884, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 60, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 448, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: Problem installing fixture '/path/to/django/dump.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I already tried to remove all signal receivers, so that none of my own code is run when executing loaddata.

Has anyone else experienced similar behaviour with django's `loaddata` and managed to get it working?

Context:

- python v3.5
- django v1.11.4
- only stdlib django model fields used

Comment: If you can use Postgresql instead of Mysql, I think it handles concurrency much more gracefully.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I could. I think this error seems to be more django-related, or do you think that using Postgresql will make it go away?

Comment: PG uses MVCC (multiversion concurrency control). I guess a modern Mysql instance may use MVCC but I don't know if this is the default setup.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 (which I am using) seems to use MVCC (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html). This makes it unlikely that a change to Postgresql will resolve this problem - if that is the issue.

Comment: This Pg/MySQL debate is a known flamewar source. I'm on the Postgresql side and I think you should give it a try. That said, it is just an opinion and  why this is a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am not a huge *SQL user, but I will definitely try Postgres if I don't find any alternative approach soon. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried Postgres, exact same error. :/

Comment: Another shot: try dumping to XML instead of JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a solution, but it did solve my problem.

After further investigation I realized that the auth.user model somehow triggered the query and broke the import.
The solution was to write a simple script to split the dump into multiple parts (I did not have access to the database anymore) and then import them in the correct order: `contenttypes`, `auth`, and the rest.

You can find the script [here](https://gist.github.com/dhaavi/ea8830207e924a151ac095730b6bd8b9).
This is how I split up the dump:

```
./investigate-django-dump.py dump.json extract contenttypes. > contenttypes.json
./investigate-django-dump.py dump.json extract auth. > auth.json
./investigate-django-dump.py dump.json extractnot auth.,contenttypes. > data.json
```